# Mid next week, mid week

Tags: word-choice

I see people write middle of next week as "mid week" or should it be "mid next week?"
What is the simple and correct way to write " the middle of next week".

May I write - "I will send the package before the middle of next week" as "I will send the package before mid next week"?

Comment: If you use the term midweek on a Monday and say "lets complete this by midweek", you are actually referring to **this Wednesday** not next Wednesday. Just thought of making that clear

Answer (score 4):

The clearest way to state something is going to happen the *middle of next week*, would be to write it as "middle of next week". There's nothing wrong with it, its concise, brief, and easily understood:

So, you may write:

> I will send the package before the middle of next week.

Edit:

However, people often do use "mid-next week". This will also be understood.

Comment: So I can write, before mid-next week too, Correct?

Comment: Yep, definitely. It's commonly used that way.

Comment: It will be understood, however, be aware that *mid-next week* is informal English, whereas *midweek* and *middle of next week* are standard forms.